# Why did my sklearn.cluster.kmeans receive an error?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

Here is my piece of code, which is copied exactly from scikit-learn:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],[10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
```

It doesn't give me the result as the written in official site, instead I received an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],[10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
----> 4 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X)
      5 kmeans.labels_

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py:1455, in KMeans.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1453 else:
   1454     kmeans_single = _kmeans_single_lloyd
-> 1455     self._check_mkl_vcomp(X, X.shape[0])
   1457 best_inertia, best_labels = None, None
   1459 for i in range(self._n_init):
   1460     # Initialize centers

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py:911, in _BaseKMeans._check_mkl_vcomp(self, X, n_samples)
    909 n_active_threads = int(np.ceil(n_samples / CHUNK_SIZE))
    910 if n_active_threads < self._n_threads:
--> 911     modules = threadpool_info()
    912     has_vcomp = "vcomp" in [module["prefix"] for module in modules]
    913     has_mkl = ("mkl", "intel") in [
    914         (module["internal_api"], module.get("threading_layer", None))
    915         for module in modules
    916     ]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py:150, in threadpool_info()
    148     return controller.info()
    149 else:
--> 150     return threadpoolctl.threadpool_info()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:124, in threadpool_info()
    107 @_format_docstring(USER_APIS=list(_ALL_USER_APIS),
    108                    INTERNAL_APIS=_ALL_INTERNAL_APIS)
    109 def threadpool_info():
    110     """Return the maximal number of threads for each detected library.
    111 
    112     Return a list with all the supported modules that have been found. Each
   (...)
    122     In addition, each module may contain internal_api specific entries.
    123     """
--> 124     return _ThreadpoolInfo(user_api=_ALL_USER_APIS).todicts()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:340, in _ThreadpoolInfo.__init__(self, user_api, prefixes, modules)
    337     self.user_api = [] if user_api is None else user_api
    339     self.modules = []
--> 340     self._load_modules()
    341     self._warn_if_incompatible_openmp()
    342 else:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:373, in _ThreadpoolInfo._load_modules(self)
    371     self._find_modules_with_dyld()
    372 elif sys.platform == "win32":
--> 373     self._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex()
    374 else:
    375     self._find_modules_with_dl_iterate_phdr()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:485, in _ThreadpoolInfo._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex(self)
    482         filepath = buf.value
    484         # Store the module if it is supported and selected
--> 485         self._make_module_from_path(filepath)
    486 finally:
    487     kernel_32.CloseHandle(h_process)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:515, in _ThreadpoolInfo._make_module_from_path(self, filepath)
    513 if prefix in self.prefixes or user_api in self.user_api:
    514     module_class = globals()[module_class]
--> 515     module = module_class(filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    516     self.modules.append(module)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:606, in _Module.__init__(self, filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    604 self.internal_api = internal_api
    605 self._dynlib = ctypes.CDLL(filepath, mode=_RTLD_NOLOAD)
--> 606 self.version = self.get_version()
    607 self.num_threads = self.get_num_threads()
    608 self._get_extra_info()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:646, in _OpenBLASModule.get_version(self)
    643 get_config = getattr(self._dynlib, "openblas_get_config",
    644                      lambda: None)
    645 get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646 config = get_config().split()
    647 if config[0] == b"OpenBLAS":
    648     return config[1].decode("utf-8")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Initially, I thought this was due to my latest version of scikit-learn so I installed the older verion 1.2.2, which is the version that google collab is using and it successfully runs the same code above on google collab, but it still got the same error.

I tried some other scikit-learn function with version 1.2.2 and they worked pretty well.

Now my version is 1.2.2

Can someone tell me what's going on and how can I solve this?

Comment: Is your Jupyter Notebook's Python version the same as your system's Python version?

Comment: I run the code on my machine & Colab -it works fine. What's your Python version?

Comment: Recently, my python version is 3.9.18, updated this morning, while my system's python version is 3.9.12. Apart from that, I tried to install cuda, cudnn and upgraded lots of python packages. Idk if this causes incompatible problems.

Comment: Before I updated the python packages, the code works well

Comment: Finally, I solved this issue on my own. It had nothing to do with the python version crashes. I followed the direction provided by the system and found out three things: scikit-learn 1.2.1, 1.3.2 and sklearn file. It may be attributed to the crashes of these files. So I uninstall them all and reinstalled then I solved the problem.